# Moving a predifined class into a thread using Qthread

Tags: multithreading, qt, qthread

I am not too great a programmer and quite new to QT sorry for my wording.

I have an already created a sensor class in Qt in a different .cpp file from main, whenever i ran my program it ran slow and lagged so my prof suggested making another thread for the class that retrieves values from sensors. I was wondering to move this class into a seperate new thread do i just simply copy and paste everything (functions calls, signals etc..) under the run() function of the new Qthread.

If this is not the procedure some help in basic terms would be quite beneficial, I dont really understand the QT index information.

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

If you are novice in Qt and especially multi threading, I recommend you to try [Qt Concurrent Framework](http://doc.qt.nokia.com/4.7/threads-qtconcurrent.html). That will at least protect you form crashes and deadlocks that hard to find out without having enough experience. Use QFuture and QFutureWatcher to execute your function in a thread and read the data.

Overall, your description is very general so I'm not sure its possible to provide a definitive answer how to use your class with QThread.

Comment: +1 This is probably the best approach to start with. If you feel you do want to use QThread though (contrary to the QThread documentation) you should not sublcass QThread. Put your logic in a QObject subclass and use moveToThread() to run it in a QThread. Some info can be found here: http://labs.qt.nokia.com/2010/06/17/youre-doing-it-wrong/